# malloc'd C string created in c file being lost when bridging to swift file on specific input

Tags: c, swift, memory-management, c-strings, bridging-header

I am making a dictionary application written in swift and c. I am using c, .h and .c, to search the dictionary text file that I have for specific traits, determined by what the user inputs into what I call the DictionaryViewController. The method of passing the input data into the c function and determining a return char* is fine however, on some input, my char* that was created does not make it to my swift file and a nil value is produced. How can I be sure that swift can access the memory I allocated from the c file?

```
//.c file

char* searchDictionary(char* u_input) {
char* returnValue = malloc(sizeof(char)*largeNumber);
//implementation
return (returnValue);
}


//.h file

char* searchDictionary(char* u_input);



//.swift file

var uin = userinput.text
let uinn = (uin as NSString).UTF8String
var uinnn = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(uinn)
var out = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(1)
out = searchDictionary(uinnn)
//out sometimes gets the value returned from searchDictionary
dictoutput.text = NSString(CString: out, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, and I don't even know Swift, but I'd expect that `var out = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(1)` causes a small memory leak.

Comment: You left out far too much code. Make a compilable complete example that demonstrates the problem. There's no need to include anything about `dictoutput` or `userinput` if the question is only about getting a string from a C file. Most likely the problem is in the code you're not showing, and is unrelated to this issue.

Comment: Ive changed `var out = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(1)` back to normal declaration in swift, `var out : UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!`. I forced the allocation because I think there is an issue with how swift is compiled. There is no problem with getting a char * from my c file. Ive printed out the contents of strlen and data right before my function exits and everything ports over when I output the length in swift as well. However, on specific input, ill get the strlen and data as normal from my c file but when i print the length and data in swift, I get nil values.

Comment: Today, Im going to try to write the output into a file and have swift access my c output that way. I used c initially so that I could use getc with my file. I think this may be a bug with the swift compiler.

Comment: Ive successfully output into a text file the contents of what the c function returns. Even though the text file has the correct value, swift still does not recognize certain output. I think there is a weird encoding issue going on turning the NSString to a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on. When working with c strings between swift and c, use `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. Using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` will produce nil values for specific input.